# how do i copy files from 1 folder to another while excluding certain file types?

Tags: windows-vista, dos

I am using windows vista.

i have a folder containing many files and subfolders.

i need to copy the contents of that folder to another without including any files of the extension .txt.

how do i do that?

Answer (score 0):

you can use [xcopy.](http://ss64.com/nt/xcopy.html). Then provide the  `/EXCLUDE:file1[+file2][+file3]...` option to exclude `.txt` files

Comment: i am not sure how to use can u explain in more details?

Answer (score 0):

On Windows Vista and further you have the tool Robocopy, a more powerful copy command which allows you to perform tasks as yours

For windows XP can be downloaded from MS from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=17657)

I suggest you running `robocopy /?` to see the options and take a look at /XF