# DOS Commands- Excluding files in a folder, using Robocopy

Tags: batch-file, dos, robocopy

I have a folder containing many other sub-folders. I am trying to write a batch file which will copy some of the folders to another place on my hard disk. I am using `xcopy` for this. The folder structure is as shown below:

```
FolderB1
  FolderB2
  FolderB22
  File1.txt
  File2.txt
  File3.txt
```

I have some `.txt` files inside FolderB1, along with FolderB2 and FolderB22. I want to copy FolderB2 and FolderB22 and skip `.txt` files contained in Folder B1

I tried using `/EXCLUDE`: param of `xcopy` command, but it is not able to perform this operation. It does not work if I specify the exclusion as `\FolderB1\*.txt` or something of this sort.

The number of main folders is not known. It can be anything. Also, there is no fix pattern for names of `.txt` files. Have checked this question too, but did not help.

Also, I want  to avoid using `del` command, since copying all and deleting again would consume time.

Can this be achieved using `Robocopy`?  Exactly similar question is raised [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7117376/dos-commands-excluding-files-in-a-folder-in-xcopy).
Any pointers would be useful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To clarify, I asume you mean to exclude all `.txt` files in `FolderB1`, but not exclude `.txt` located elsewhere.

You can do that with robocopy in two steps. First copy all files except any `.txt`. And in the second step copy only `.txt` files, but exclude `FolderB1`.

```
robocopy c:\source c:\destination /s /xf *.txt
robocopy c:\source c:\destination *.txt /s /xd c:\source\FolderB1
```